# I can add event animation but I can't add keyframe?

Tags: unity, animation

I am trying to add animation to my UI panel but the problem is I can't add a keyframe to my animation (the button is grayed out). But I can add event animation (the button is not grayed out).

Here is [the video](https://youtu.be/UhkVTx5YmMU) of what's happening.
Anyone know how I can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a property first. Then you will be able to keyframe that property.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP.  However, additionally, the Add Property button lets me select the property I want to add but when I click the Plus button for the property nothing is added to the Animation clip's timeline.